# Emmet и Phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm, emmet

Добрый день.
Подскажите кто сведущ Phpstorm имеет встроенную поддержку Emmet. Но когда я пытаюсь использовать shortcats из доков еммета, они не работают. http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/
Например html:5 нажимаю таб и ничего не происходит, что касается обычного использоватния типа div>ul>li.jimclass работает ок. Не пойму в чем дело. Может нужна дополнительная настройка среды?

Comment: Все разобрался. Из за импорта старых темлейтов затерлись шорткаты еммета.

Answer (score 0):

Просто вводишь ! и нажимаешь таб и будет тебе html5